# WGAN-GP Loss formalization

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, loss, wasserstein-metric, wasserstein-gan

I have to write the formalization of the loss function of my network, built following the WGAN-GP model. The discriminator takes 3 consecutive images as input (such as 3 consecutive frames of a video) and must evaluate if the intermediate image is a possible image between the first and the third.
[image]

I thought something like this, but is it correct to identify x1, x2 and x3 coming from Pr even if they are 3 consecutive images? Only the first is chosen randomly, the others are simply the next two.

**EDIT**:

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

I replaced Pr with p_r(x1, x3) and p_r(x1, x2, x3) to reinforce the fact that x2 and x3 are taken after x1, so they depend on the choice of x1. Is it more correct this way?
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that the generator for $\tilde{x}$ is being conditioned on $x_1, x_3$? Also that $\hat{x}$ is a random mix of real $x_2$ and a generated $\tilde{x}$?

Comment: @NeilSlater yes, I confirm. I added a change to the original post under EDIT regarding the second thing

Comment: Please, put your main **specific** question in the title.